# What does this notation means? (proof of Picard–Lindelöf theorem in wikipedia)

Tags: general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, notation

I was read a detailed proof of [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem). And, in this article of Wikipedia I found a notation some weird.
I saw that:
$$\overline {I_{a}(t_{0})} = [t_0-a,t_0+a]$$
$$\overline {B_{b}(y_{0})} = [y_0-b,y_0+b]$$
This is al normal, it is a definition.
But after, I saw:

$$\displaystyle \Gamma : {\mathcal {C}} \ ( \ I_{a}(t_{0}) \ , \ B_{b}(y_{0}) \ )\longrightarrow {\mathcal {C}} \ ( \ I_{a}(t_{0}) \ , \ B_{b}(y_{0}) \ )$$

So, What does this line over the letter mean? It is an error? Because I had the idea that it is:

$$\displaystyle \Gamma : {\mathcal {C}} \ \left( \ \overline {I_{a}(t_{0})} \ , \ \overline {B_{b}(y_{0})} \ \right)\longrightarrow {\mathcal {C}} \ \left( \ \overline {I_{a}(t_{0})} \ , \ \overline {B_{b}(y_{0})} \ \right)$$

The other thing is, according to me, the theorem should have a proof with $\overline {B_{b}(y_{0})} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, but $\overline {B_{b}(y_{0})}$ is a interval in this proof.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: I don't see any 'hat' anywhere.

Comment: I wanted to say "line over the letter", thank you

Comment: An overline is usually to denote closure. For example if $I = (a, b)$ is an open interval, then it's closure is $\overline{I} = [a, b]$.

Comment: So, there is a possibility that it is an error?

Comment: The proof is for $n=1$, so a closed ball reduces to a compact interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the wikipedia entry is sub-optimal. There should be mention of a domain $\cal D$ of $f$ in the first statement in the intro, later that the cylinder $\bar I_a\times \bar B_b$ has to be a sub-set of $\cal D$.

And you need the closed sets, first for compactness to have a maximum $M$ of $f$ over the cylinder and later for completeness of the function space as you apply the Banach fixed-point theorem.

(Btw., there is no need to invoke Grönwall, as the BFS already supplies the uniqueness of the fixed point.)

---

In short, as always with the things written in wikipedia, look for other sources (more than one). For this topic, preferably find text books, as the proofs there are usually more carefully composed.